# How to pass data to my xml tag that's inside CDATA in Java?

Tags: java, xml, cdata, string.format

my xml is "**req.xml**"

```
<soapenv:Body>
 <ser:processRequest>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <ser:in0>
   <![CDATA[ <ItemRq> <ItemId> %s </ItemId> </ItemRq>]]> <!--Item value in CDATA tag -->
  </ser:in0>    
 </ser:processRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Without CDATA we can pass Value to ItemId through `string.format`. But this code is not working while the xml is in the CDATA tag. How can I pass value to `ItemId` tag that is in the CDATA?

```
String xml = convertStreamToString(getAssets().open("req.xml"));
String request = String.format(xml, "2499");
```

Comment: Would you (please) consider using an XML library?

Comment: Sorry i am a beginner. where can i find them?

Comment: What actually you wants to perform ? No clarity on the question.

Comment: As i mentioned i want to pass a value of itemid in between the xml tag <ItemId> %s </ItemId> thats in CDATA